# How to use lwd for specific points

Tags: r, plot, lines

I would like to change the thickness of the line between two points [(4,1) and (5,0)] in R Plot.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
y <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)

plot(x, y, type="b", ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE, pch = 20, lwd=ifelse(x>=4 & x<=5, 3, 1))
```

But, I am only able to make the points thicker. I also need to make the line thicker. Could you guys advice me on where I am wrong.

[image: Plot]

I tried with lines and segments. I get a line that is touching both the points. But, I need the thicker line to be of the same length as other lines. [image]

Solved using `lines`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With plot, `lwd` can't accept a vector.  You might want to try using `lines` instead

```
plot(x, y, type="b", ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE, pch = 20)

lines(x[4:5], y[4:5], lwd = 3, type = "b")
```

Answer (score 1):

Segments takes (x0,y0) and draws to (x1,y1)

```
segments(x[4],y[4],x[5],y[5], lwd=3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. is it possible to also make the length of the new line same as other lines.

Answer (score 0):

`plot` alone cannot actually do what you want. You need to call `plot` and then `segments`.

```
XMIN = 4
XMAX = 5

plot(x, y, type="b", ann = FALSE, axes = FALSE, pch = 20)
xinds = x>=XMIN & x<=XMAX
segments(x[xinds][1:sum(xinds)-1],y[xinds][1:sum(xinds)-1],
         x[xinds][2:sum(xinds)],y[xinds][2:sum(xinds)], lwd=3)
```